# FileInfo.BaseName exists in PowerShell but not in straight .NET

Tags: .net, powershell

Why is it that in .NET the `System.IO.FileInfo` object does not have a `BaseName` property, but I can use the property through PowerShell, e.g.:

```
$FolderItems = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" | Where-Object {$_ -isnot [IO.DirectoryInfo]}

foreach ($FolderItem in $FolderItems)
{
    write-host $FolderItem.BaseName 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Powershell adds that property for you.  If you run get-member on a fileinfo object, you can see that it's a script property, and even the script itself:

```
get-item testfile1.txt | Get-Member BaseName | format-list

TypeName   : System.IO.FileInfo
Name       : BaseName
MemberType : ScriptProperty
Definition : System.Object BaseName {get=if ($this.Extension.Length -gt 0){$this.Name.Remove($this.Name.Length - 
         $this.Extension.Length)}else{$this.Name};}
```

Comment: Indeed and to see "just" the extended properties execute: `(get-item testfile1.txt).psextended`.

Comment: Interesting.  Been using .NET for years, and I'm learning PS finally.  Thanks all

Answer (score 5):

Because BaseName isn't a Property, it's a ScriptProperty.

```
Name                      MemberType     Definition                                                                     
----                      ----------     ---------- 
BaseName                  ScriptProperty System.Object BaseName {get=if ($this.Extension.Length -gt 0){$this.Name.Remove($this.Name.Length - $this.Extension.Length)}else{$this.Name};}
```

To clarify, it is a calculated response that PowerShell gives you derived from other properties of the object. It is not itself a direct property of a `System.IO.FileInfo` object. When you ask PowerShell for the BaseName value it looks at the Name value, checks if there is an Extension value, and then truncates the Extension value from the Name value and returns the result.

Edit: Amazing how somebody else answers the question 2 minutes after me with a virtually identical answer and they get twice as many up votes and are marked as the answer. `</nerdrage>`

Comment: Please only take this as constructive criticism because you were wondering why the other answer got more votes and was accepted: I accepted that answer because I found it more concise and because the block of code is more useful.  The output block you posted doesn't seem to show something germane to the question, and it doesn't even show the command you used to get that output.  Still, I upvoted you because, while less concise and, in my opinion, lacking a useful code example, you still ultimately stated the same thing as the answer that I accepted.