# Powershell script for comparing two directories based on file names only

Tags: powershell

I have two disks which has the same directory structure. `C:\Files` and `D:\Files`

Both `C:\Files` and `D:\Files` have multiple directories under them but have the same name etc, but the files inside them differ in extension. In `C:\Files` they are `*.csv` and in `D:\Files`, a process monitors the files (copied from `C:\`) and once it is done changes the files to `*.processed`.

I want a script that would do that copy. I.e copy files from `C:\Files` to `D:\Files` which have not been processed by comparing only the file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this. The property you want to compare on is called `BaseName` which powershell helpfully adds for you to the `IO.FileSystemInfo` class ([FileInfo.BaseName exists in PowerShell but not in straight .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739926/fileinfo-basename-exists-in-powershell-but-not-in-straight-net)). `BaseName` is **just** the name of the file, and doesn't contain any of the extensions that you don't care about.

```powershell
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\files -Recurse -File -Filter "*.csv"
$destinationFiles = Get-ChildItem D:\files -Recurse -File 

foreach($sourceFile in $sourceFiles) {
  $exists = $destinationFiles | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -eq $sourceFile.BaseName}
  if(!$exists) {
    Copy-Item $sourceFile.fullname -Destination "D:\Files\$($sourceFile.BaseName)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dir .\ *csv -Recurse -File | cp -ea Ignore -WhatIf -Destination {
    $dest=$_.FullName-replace'^C:','D:'-replace'\.csv','.processed'
    if(Test-Path $dest){
        Write-Host Already exists -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $null
    }else{
        Write-Host Copying... -ForegroundColor Green
        $dest-replace'\.processed$','.csv'
    }
}
```

Notice the WhatIf parameter: you must remove it, if you're going to really copy the items.
Also, you may like to remove the 2 lines with`write-host` cmdlet.
Notive too, that I have hard-coded the `C:` and `D:` drives as source and destine drives.